# Article Settings Priority (again...)

Tags: articles

Is there a way to make the individual article options settings take priority over the Menu or Global options settings? I have found that it makes no difference what the individual article options are set to - the Global and Menu options determine what article information is shown (This is not true for the Mainmenu -> Home menu - that has an option to "Use Article Settings" and then the Article options take priority, but no other Menu has that option).

This seems like a simple thing - the individual Article settings should always take priority, but it doesn't seem to be the case. Is there some way to change / fix that? I'm working with Joomla 3.9.6.

Thanks all...

Comment: Which settings? Can we have some context with your question please?  Can you tell us specifically what you want to change? How about a screenshot with some notes/scribbling on it?

Comment: I'm asking about ANY of the Article Option settings. For example "Show Author". For the Mainmenu -> Home item, one of the options is "Use Article Settings". For any other menu item (including any Mainmenu item except Home), that option is not there. And since it's not there, I can't see anyway to override the Menu settings for the Article Options. And I have screenshots to illustrate what I mean, but I don't see any way to upload them.